# Python3 how does __init__.py store package information?

Tags: python

I noticed something intressting when moving a python file out of it's python package and into another project.

I had a strucutre that looked like this

```
 mypackage
   __init__.py
   myfile.py
   myotherfile.py
```

So I wanted to move myfile.py to another project so i simply dragged and dropped it. But when I ran the original project `__init__.py` seem to keep some kind of reference to the file i just dragged out of the package and kept trying to reference myfile.py.

So my question is how do you reset the `__init__.py` to update it's references?

Comment: Most likely your IDE tried to adjust your imports. Simply change them back manually

Comment: What is the content of that `__init__.py`?

Comment: `__init__.py` is just a Python script with a special name, it doesn't store anything unless you ask it to